# Install library in databricks from private maven repository

Tags: maven, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to install a library from Maven in Databricks. The repository is private. I'm trying to install it using a repository like https://user:pass@host/, but it gives me 'unresolved dependency'. When I try to download it from mvn cli, then it works.

Any ideas?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: just adding comment to check if its possible now after 2 years.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, installing libraries from Maven private repositories is not support in Azure Databricks.

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/libraries/), Azure Databricks has the ability to install third-party or custom libraries from the Maven public repository and not from private maven repository.

As an alternate solution, you can upload library file in dbfs and install from there.